# Splash screen not appearing on Xamarin.Forms Android app with VPN and managed device on a Work profile

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen

We have very strange situation where the splash screen of the Android application is not appearing when we deploy on managed device in the work profile with VPN, but everything is working on a personal profile on the same device. Does anyone have the same issue or any suggestions what might be causing this behaviour?

For the completeness: The same or similar error occurres when using Titanium and is described here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-26872

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use to set the splash screen to the main launcher activity's "windowBackground" style in XML. The OS displays the "windowBackground" on the startup of the application, but in our case, the app is being launched by Android Enterprise within a sandboxed environment and the "windowBackground" image is ignored. So, this seems to be an issue with Android Enterprise.

The solution:

1. Create a separate SplashActivity set the MainLauncher = true(Make sure no other activity has the MainLauncher set to true).
2. Create SplashLayout.xml for the SplashActivity.
3. In the OnCreate of the SplashActivity after base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState),
   set the content of the activity:  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashLayout);
4. Start the MainActivity: RunOnUiThread(() => StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity)));
5. Do a delay based on your needs after the  StartActivity call.
6. Call Finish() wright after the delay like that the user will not be able to return back to the splash screen with a hit of the back button.